# Sunrise calendar firefox

Tags: firefox, calendar

I'm trying to use sunrise.am on firefox, and I can't figure out why it keeps getting me this error :

"We could not load a supported database (IndexedDB, WebSQL, or LocalStorage).
Are you in private browsing mode? These database features are not supported in private browsing.
Sorry for the inconvenience."

I'm at work behind a proxy, but it only happens with firefox, it's OK with Chrome or IE.
I am not un private browsing mode.

Did it already happen to someone?

Comment: This does not seem to be a question about programming, but about the use of a website and so outside of the scope of this site.

Comment: Hi. The underlying question is : what firefox parameter may block a website from loading a local database?